# Firebase Admin SDK update only given arguments

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have a firebase project that includes firebase cloud functions, one of which is set to update a user both in auth and inside a 'Users' collection. I want to create a single function called updateUser where it updates the attributes sent in the request only. The problem is that I can't figure out how to tell the function not to set/update this attribute if not sent in the request, for instance:
Note: the code below is in typescript

```
    //update user using firebase auth
    const res = await admin.auth().updateUser(uid,
        {
            password: data.password,
            photoURL: data.photoURL,
        }
```

How can I tell the function to update password only if data.password exists ? A turnery/if statement is not allowed inside a admin.auth(). UpdateRequest instance.

Answer (score 0):

The `updateUser` call updates all properties that you pass in. So if you want a certain property to not be updated, don't pass it into the call.

For example:

```
let updates = {};
if (data.password) updates.password = data.password;
if (data.photoURL) updates.photoURL = data.photoURL;

const res = await admin.auth().updateUser(uid, updates);
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I though of constructing the updates before calling the function, the issue is, what is the type of 'upates' ? A regular map does not do it, the documentation states that the map of data passed in is of type  admin.auth(). UpdateRequest